# Collapsible product categories on sidebar?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, widgets

I'm trying to find out how to make a collapsible product categories on the product page sidebar. I'm using woocommerce and the Avada theme.

I've tried scouring google to find a plugin for this or just get me in the right direction of doing it myself, if I can.

Here is a picture of my current product sidebar

[image: product page sidebar]

As you can see it's a bit messy.

Hoping someone can help me. Thank you

Comment: actually it is showing the hierarchial order itselt. do you want to modify the style?

Comment: Actually, it's just showing in a hierarchial style, but I want it to be collapsible when the user clicks it, hiding the children and grandchilren of the categories.

I actually have a lot of categories listed, so if it's not collapsible, it can look pretty messy and unorganized

Comment: if you are using Avada theme, you can override it's functions via child theme.